# "Unable to load popup - please try again" when popups are already showing

Tags: feature-request, popups

When a popup is already showing on the screen, clicking on the link that opened it again leads to an "Unable to load popup - please try again" error.
Could a more descriptive error be shown in this case, when a popup is already visible, something like "You already have an open popup, please close it before trying to open another one"?

[image: screenshot]